# In Boost.Test, how to obtain the name of current test?

Tags: boost, boost-test

In `Boost.Test`, how can I obtain the name of the current auto test case?

Example:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyTest)
{
  std::cerr << "Starting " << test_name << std::endl;
  // lots of code here
  std::cerr << "Ending " << test_name << std::endl;
}
```

In the example, I want the variable `test_name` to contain "MyTest".

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/boost-list/ZzFmu14UfeQ), so far it works for me

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is an undocumented* function that may be called for that purpose. The following line will flush the name of the current test to `cerr`:

```
#include <boost/test/framework.hpp>

...

std::cerr << boost::unit_test::framework::current_test_case().p_name 
          << std::endl;
```

Note however that using this API does not flush the parameters in case of parametrized tests.

You might also be interested in the [test checkpoints](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/checkpoints.html)** (which seems to be what you want to do.)

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

...

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MyTest)
{
  BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT("Starting");
  // lots of code here
  BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT("Ending");
}
```

**EDIT**

* The `current_test_case()` function is now documented, see [the official Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/unit_test/framework/current_test_case.html).

** `BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT` was previously called `BOOST_CHECKPOINT`. See the [Boost changelog (1.35.0)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/test_tools/reference/deprecated.html).

Comment: However, I do not menage to use that name when I use --run_test=<THE PRINTED NAME>, can only get to run my test using wildcards, I cannot get the exact test name, weird!!

Comment: Solved, I had to specify also the test suite, and do `--run_test=<TEST_SUITE>/<THE PRINTED NAME>`!

Comment: I added a link to the documentation + the missing include.

Comment: And while I was there, I also fixed the `BOOST_CHECKPOINT` macros.

Comment: Thanks! I also hit this

Comment: `boost::unit_test::framework::current_test_case().full_name()` is more idiomatic. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/unit_test/test_case.html#idm46165629438208-bb

Answer (score 1):

[A different question about suite names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491113/get-boost-test-test-suite-name-inside-a-test-case) gives a way to extract the name rather than just printing it:

```
auto test_name = std::string(boost::unit_test::framework::current_test_case().p_name)
```