# Get BOOST TEST test suite name inside a test case

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

I'm using `BOOST TEST` and I wonder if there is a way to find out the `test suite` from inside the `test case`. I know that I can find `test case`'s name by:

`boost::unit_test::framework::current_test_case().p_name`

Is there a way to find out the suite name also?

My suites-cases structure is:

`suite ---> case 1`

`______|--> case 2`

`______|--> case 3`

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `unit_test` has not only `p_name` but also `p_parent_id`, which is the ID of the test suite. Both those properties are inherited from `test_unit`, which is the common base class for `unit_test` and `test_suite`.

To get the suite from the ID, we can look at how `current_test_case` works:

```
test_case const&
current_test_case()
{
    return get<test_case>( s_frk_impl().m_curr_test_case );
}
```

The `m_curr_test_case` member is a `test_unit_id`, just like `p_parent_id`. So, to get the test suite of the current test case, you can use this:

```
framework::get<test_suite>(current_test_case().p_parent_id)
```

Finally, `test_suite` has a `p_name` property just like `unit_test`, so you should find the name there.

Comment: Thanks! I used: `(boost::unit_test::framework::get<boost::unit_test::test_suite>(prnt_id_t)).p_name`, while `prnt_id_t` is: `boost::unit_test::framework::current_test_case().p_parent_id;`